# Plotly dash callback return is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am using dcc.DatePickerSingle. The user selects a date, the date gets attached to the end of a file path to access certain files. I then load those files in within the update function, modify them, and send them out as a dictionary. However, I keep getting this error, which doesn't make sense.

The error says this:

```
InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback for property `children` of component `date_picker`
returned a value which is not JSON serializable.

In general, Dash properties can only be dash components, strings,
dictionaries, numbers, None, or lists of those.
```

However, I am explicitly returning a dictionary. For example, here are the final two lines inside the update function.

```
print(type(final_dict))
return(final_dict)
```

The print statement returns `<class 'dict'>`.

Full code---

```
app = JupyterDash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SLATE])

parent_dirs = ["/Users/eli.turaskyriskpulse.com/Documents/Python_data/plotly_practice/timeseries_data/ecmwf/ensemble/",
               "/Users/eli.turaskyriskpulse.com/Documents/Python_data/plotly_practice/timeseries_data/ecmwf/operational/",
               "/Users/eli.turaskyriskpulse.com/Documents/Python_data/plotly_practice/timeseries_data/gfs/ensemble/",
               "/Users/eli.turaskyriskpulse.com/Documents/Python_data/plotly_practice/timeseries_data/gfs/operational/"]

controls = dbc.Card(
    [   dbc.FormGroup([
                dcc.DatePickerSingle(
                    id='my-date-picker-single',
                    min_date_allowed=dt.date(2018, 4, 17),
                    max_date_allowed=dt.date(2020, 10, 6),
                    initial_visible_month=dt.date(2020, 10, 6),
                    date=dt.date(2020, 10, 6)
            ),
        ],
    ),
        dbc.FormGroup(
                dcc.RadioItems(
                    id='hour_radio',
                    options=[{'label': '00z', 'value': '00z'},
                            {'label': '12z', 'value': '12z'}],
                    value='00z',
                    labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'},
                    inputStyle={"margin-left": "15px","margin-right": "5px"}
                ),
            ),
        ],
     )
app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        html.Hr(),
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col([
                dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col(controls)
                ],  align="start"), 
            ],xs = 2)
            ,
            dbc.Col([
                dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col([html.Div(id = 'date_picker')],)
                ]),
            ])
        ],), 
    ],
    fluid=True,
)

@app.callback(
    Output('date_picker', 'children'),
    [Input('my-date-picker-single', 'date'),
     Input('hour_radio', 'value')])

def update_output(date_value, radio2):
    if radio2=='00z':
        if date_value is not None:
            date_object = dt.date.fromisoformat(date_value)
            date_string = date_object.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H')
            print(date_string)
            out_files=[]
            for i in parent_dirs:
                out_files.append(os.path.join(i, date_string))
            #print(out_files)
            model_dict={}
            for i in out_files:
                corn_pre=glob.glob(i+"/*corn*.nc")
                soybeans_pre=glob.glob(i+"/*soybeans*.nc")
                winterwheat_pre=glob.glob(i+"/*winterwheat*.nc")
                springwheat_pre=glob.glob(i+"/*springwheat*.nc")
                
                crop_dict={}
                crop_dict['corn']=xr.open_mfdataset(corn_pre)
                crop_dict['soybeans']=xr.open_mfdataset(soybeans_pre)
                crop_dict['winterwheat']=xr.open_mfdataset(winterwheat_pre)
                crop_dict['springwheat']=xr.open_mfdataset(springwheat_pre)
                
                file_name=corn_pre[0].split('/')[-1]
                model_dict_key=file_name[12:18]
                model_dict[model_dict_key]=crop_dict

                
                today=dt.date.today()
            final_dict={}

            for i in model_dict.keys():
                model_dict1={}
                for j in model_dict[i]:
                    df_vals={}
                    df_prod={}
                    df_area={}


                    #print(j, i, k)
                    df_vals[j]=model_dict[i][j].to_dataframe().reset_index()
                    df_prod[j]=df_vals[j].filter(regex='prod')
                    df_area[j]=df_vals[j].filter(regex='area')

                    if i=='ec_ens':
                        df_prod[j]['time']=pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H'), (pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H')+dt.timedelta(days=15)), freq='6H')
                        df_area[j]['time']=pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H'), (pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H')+dt.timedelta(days=15)), freq='6H')
                    if i=='ec_op_':
                        times1=pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H'), pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H')+dt.timedelta(days=6), freq='3H')
                        times2=pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H')+dt.timedelta(days=6), pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H')+dt.timedelta(days=10), freq='6H')
                        df_prod[j]['time']=times1.union(times2)
                        df_area[j]['time']=times1.union(times2)
                    if i=='gfs_en':
                        times1=pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H'), pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H')+dt.timedelta(days=10), freq='3H')
                        times2=pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H')+dt.timedelta(days=10), pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H')+dt.timedelta(days=16), freq='6H')
                        df_prod[j]['time']=times1.union(times2)
                        df_area[j]['time']=times1.union(times2)
                    if i=='gfs_op':
                        df_prod[j]['time']=pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H'), pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H')+dt.timedelta(days=16), freq='3H')
                        df_area[j]['time']=pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H'), pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%Y%m%d_%H')+dt.timedelta(days=16), freq='3H')

                    for m in df_prod.keys():
                        for n in df_prod[m].columns:
                            #print(n)
                            if n=='2m_temp_24hdelta_prod':
                                df_prod[m]=df_prod[m].rename(columns={'2m_temp_24hdelta_prod': '24h Delta Temp'})
                            if n=='2m_temp_prod':
                                df_prod[m]=df_prod[m].rename(columns={'2m_temp_prod': 'Temperature'})
                            if n=='snowfall_prod':
                                df_prod[m]=df_prod[m].rename(columns={'snowfall_prod': "Total Snow"})
                            if n=='total_precip_24hdelta_prod':
                                df_prod[m]=df_prod[m].rename(columns={'total_precip_24hdelta_prod': '24h Delta Precip'})
                            if n=='total_precip_prod':
                                df_prod[m]=df_prod[m].rename(columns={'total_precip_prod': 'Total Precip'})                     

                        for n in df_area[m].columns:
                            #print(n)
                            if n=='2m_temp_24hdelta_area':
                                df_area[m]=df_area[m].rename(columns={'2m_temp_24hdelta_area': '24h Delta Temp'})
                            if n=='2m_temp_area':
                                df_area[m]=df_area[m].rename(columns={'2m_temp_area': 'Temperature'})
                            if n=='snowfall_area':
                                df_area[m]=df_area[m].rename(columns={'snowfall_area': "Total Snow"})
                            if n=='total_precip_24hdelta_area':
                                df_area[m]=df_area[m].rename(columns={'total_precip_24hdelta_area': '24h Delta Precip'})
                            if n=='total_precip_area':
                                df_area[m]=df_area[m].rename(columns={'total_precip_area': 'Total Precip'})      

                        crop_dict={}
                        crop_dict={'Production':df_prod,'Area':df_area} 
                        model_dict1[j]=crop_dict
                        #print(model_dict1.keys())
                    final_dict[i]=model_dict1
            final_dict['EC ENS']=final_dict.pop('ec_ens')
            final_dict['EC OP']=final_dict.pop('ec_op_')
            final_dict['GFS ENS']=final_dict.pop('gfs_en')
            final_dict['GFS OP']=final_dict.pop('gfs_op')
        print(type(final_dict))
        return(final_dict)
```

Comment: Maybe use a debugger to inspect the contents of the dictionary before the serialization is attempted, and see if it contains anything unexpected, namely a date picker. And it'd be helpful if you posted it here, too, since your post doesn't contain a [mre].

Comment: Oh wait. Can the dictionary itself not contain dataframes?

Comment: What do you mean here by debugging? It's a nested dictionary. Not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: Looks this issue is actually solved using dcc.Store, something I am now investigating.